# javascript check form for radio group

Tags: javascript

HiExperts,

I am creating a form with a javascript validation function for a radio group. The idea is, when "None" is checked, no div pop up, and when "Monday" or "Tuesday" is checked, a div pop up:-

```
//the form
<form name="form_sf" id = "form_sf" method="post" action="process.php" onSubmit="return check_sf_form_info(form_sf,'all')">

<input name="date" id="date" type="radio" value="nil" onChange="check_sf_form_info(form_sf,2)" />None

<input name="date" id="date" type="radio" value="mon" onChange="check_sf_form_info(form_sf,2)" />Monday

<input name="date" id="date" type="radio" value="tue"  onChange="check_sf_form_info(form_sf,2)" />Tuesday

</form>

//the javascript

function check_sf_form_info(form,mark,edit){
        if(mark==2 || mark=="all"){
     if(form.date.value!=="nil"){
       price.innerHTML="$100";
       price.style.display="block";
       price.style.height="auto";
     }else{
       price.innerHTML="";
       price.style.display = "none";       
     }
   }
}
```

Would experts please teach me where I have done wrongly? Thanksalot!

Comment: TRy to trace yourself & `alert` what you getting in `mark` , `form.date.value` etc...It will gonna help you

Comment: In HTML, you can only use an `id` **once**. Please give unique IDs to your elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nil radio button is the first item in the radio groups.
therefore you can use 'getElementsByName' functions.

```
function check_sf_form_info(form,mark,edit){
     var radio_date_nil = document.getElementsByName('date');
     if(mark==2 || mark=="all"){
     if(radio_date_nil[0].value!=="nil"){
       price.innerHTML="$100";
       price.style.display="block";
       price.style.height="auto";
     }else{
       price.innerHTML="";
       price.style.display = "none";       
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing all of your onchanges to `onChange="check_sf_form_info(this,2)"` then changing your function to:

```
function check_sf_form_info(radio,mark,edit){
   if(mark==2 || mark=="all"){
     if(radio.value!="nil"){
       price.innerHTML="$100";
       price.style.display="block";
       price.style.height="auto";
     }else{
       price.innerHTML="";
       price.style.display = "none";       
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: On a sort of side note... you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id attribute on the same page. If you need to retrieve one of those elements by id it will not work like this.